# regarding predicted value from xgboost package in R

Tags: r, prediction, xgboost

package using: 
‘xgboost’ version 0.4-4

i am using model building function xgboost() using code :

```
fit <- xgboost(data =sparse_matrix , label = trainSet$OutputClass, 
                max.depth  = 4,eta = 1, nthread = 2, nround = 10, 
                eval_metric = "merror",objective =  "multi:softmax",num_class = 45)
```

when i use the prediction function:

```
Prediction<- predict(fit,sparse_matrixtestSet)
```

the above code gave output as below( instead of class names its giving    numerical equivalent value eventhough "label = trainSet$OutputClass" contain class names)

output:

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 35 3 3 3 4 31 7 7 7 3 3 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 10 10 11 
[27] 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 14 14   10 10 
[53] 15 15   15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16  18 18 18 
[79] 18 18 18 18 35 35 35 18 21 21 21 21 32 1 1 25 25 25 25 26 27 27 27 27  27 27 
[105] 27 27 29 29 29 29 29 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 35 35 32 32 32 43 43 32 32   
[131] 32 32 32 32 32 32 43 32 32 32 32 32 33
```

I have also set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` while reading data set.

Can Someone Please help me How to Get predicted values in terms of class names instead of numerical values...
Thanks in advance